# How do I change the shape of a button in Material UI using theme?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-design, material-ui

So the documentation on `Button` component has various sections and also a Codesandbox linked at https://codesandbox.io/s/npie4

However, there is nowhere mentioned how to change the shape of a button if needed.

[image]

I am using Google Material Sketch [file](https://material.io/resources/theme-editor/) and I want the buttons to be rounded

[image]

How can I do that using the `theme` object so that in my entire app the `Button` component are always rounded?

Comment: these buttons already exist in material ui , https://material-ui.com/components/floating-action-button/

Answer (score 54, accepted):

There is a global border radius shape value in the theme. You can change it like this:

```
const theme = createMuiTheme({
  shape: {
    borderRadius: 8,
  }, 
})
```

Alternatively, if you are only interested in the button style:

```
const theme = createMuiTheme({
  overrides: {
    MuiButton: {
      root: {
        borderRadius: 8,
      }, 
    }, 
  }, 
})
```

Or, you could target the global class name of the button:

```
.MuiButton-root {
  border-radius: 8px;
}
```

Comment: How can I use it as a "rounded" prop? (like in Vuetify)

Answer (score 15):

In Material UI v5.0+, you can easily approach that with this:

```
<Button type="submit" color="primary" sx={ { borderRadius: 28 } }>Enter</Button>
```

If you want to reuse the same style, you can import it from an external file and your code would be something like this:

```
<Button type="submit" color="primary" sx={ { ...styles.button.rounded } }>Enter</Button>
```

Alternatively to affect all buttons - globally via theme (Material UI v5):

```
import { createTheme } from '@mui/material';

const theme = createTheme({
  components: {
    MuiButton: {
      styleOverrides: {
        root: {
          borderRadius: 28,
        },
      }, 
    }, 
  },
});
```

I also tried it by creating a new variant (new in v5.0) but I think is more complicated because you'll have to add many styles by each prop that is added:

*createTheme function*

```
MuiButton: {
            defaultProps: {
                variant: 'contained',
                color: 'inherit'
            },
            styleOverrides: {
                containedInherit: {
                    backgroundColor: '#fff'
                }
            },
            variants: [
                {
                    props: { variant: 'rounded' },
                    style: {
                        borderRadius: 28
                    }
                },
                {
                    props: { variant: 'rounded', color: 'primary' },
                    style: {
                        color: 'white',
                        backgroundColor: '#01697d'
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
```

Besides, with **sx prop** solution, you can combine variants with round style (outlined and contained).

Comment: Awesome, just what I was looking for. Didn't know this existed.

Answer (score 7):

If you want to have a **ahem** well rounded `Button`, use [`Fab`](https://mui.com/components/floating-action-button/):

```
<Fab>
  <Icon />
</Fab>
<Fab variant="extended">
  <Icon sx={{ mr: 1 }} />
  Extended
</Fab>
```

> How can I use it as a "rounded" prop? (like in Vuetify)

You can add custom styling props like `rounded` in **MUI v5** by using `styled` to create an enhanced version of the original component with extra styles and whatever props you want to customize it:

```
import MuiButton from '@mui/material/Button';
import { styled } from '@mui/material/styles';

const options = {
  shouldForwardProp: (prop) => prop !== 'rounded',
};
const Button = styled(
  MuiButton,
  options,
)(({ theme, rounded }) => ({
  borderRadius: rounded ? '24px' : null,
}));
```

```
<Button variant="contained">Rectangle</Button>
<Button variant="contained" rounded>
  Round
</Button>
```

To change the `borderRadius` globally, you can use `createTheme`, note that this approach also affects other components which reference `theme.shape.borderRadius` like `Accordion` or `Skeleton`:

```
const theme = createTheme({
  shape: {
    borderRadius: 5,
  },
});
```

### Live Demo

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

Answer (score 2):

Why not just add a `borderRadius` in `makeStyles`?

```
const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  button: {
    margin: theme.spacing(1),
    borderRadius: "5em"
  },
  input: {
    display: 'none',
  },
}));
```

Example: https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-f00qi?fontsize=14

Comment: Thank you, however, I needed to fit that in `theme`, so I accepted another answer, but your works too when someone needs to do one-time work

Answer (score -1):

I don't believe there is a material-ui class for this. You could just make a custom class yourself to achieve it though:

```
.rounded-corners {
   border-radius: 25px;
}
```